# How to write to shared library code segment loaded into RAM memory?

Tags: memory, c, mmap

I would like you to ask **why I cannot write** to the loaded shared library code segment in RAM memory in Linux 2.6.28.9 on MIPS CPU platform (LG TV). I am able to read bytes but not able to write anything. In the example source code below (cross-compiled in gcc) I get **ERROR 22: Invalid argument (EINVAL)** when *write()* function is called.

```
// this app tries to replace 4 bytes in code segment memory of loaded shared library

#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <stdlib.h> // off_t
#include <dlfcn.h>  // dlopen, dlclose
#include <fcntl.h>  // open, O_RDWR
#include <unistd.h> // lseek, close, read
#include <errno.h>  // errno
#include <string.h> // strerror
#include <sys/mman.h>   // mprotect, PROT_READ, PROT_WRITE, PROT_EXEC

#define BYTES_TO_REPLACE    4

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int fd, pid;
   unsigned *handle;
   unsigned long pagesize;
   off_t fun_addr, pa_fun_addr;
   unsigned char buf[BYTES_TO_REPLACE];
   char s[100];

   // initialize
   pagesize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);    // memory page size from system
   pid = getpid();          // PID of current process

   // open shared library file, OK
   handle = dlopen("/path_to_library_files/shared_library.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);

   // get function address, OK
   fun_addr = (off_t)dlsym(handle, "function_name_in_lib");

   // open memory device (pseudo-file), OK
   sprintf(s, "/proc/%d/mem", pid); // memory space of our process (/proc/self/mem)
   //strcpy(s, "/dev/mem");     // in that case when reading from memory ==> ERROR 14: Bad address
   fd = open(s, O_RDWR);        // open for reading and writing

   // go to starting address of the library function loaded earlier, OK
   lseek(fd, fun_addr, SEEK_SET);

   // read from memory, OK
   read(fd, buf, BYTES_TO_REPLACE);
   printf("old replaced bytes = [%02X %02X %02X %02X]\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]);

   // move back, OK
   lseek(fd, fun_addr, SEEK_SET);

   // unprotect memory page - no error, but does not help
   pa_fun_addr = (fun_addr / pagesize) * pagesize;  // page-aligned address
   mprotect((void *)pa_fun_addr, pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);

   // write new data to memory: ERROR 22: Invalid argument
   buf[0] = 0x08; buf[1] = 0x00; buf[2] = 0xE0; buf[3] = 0x03;  // replacing 4-byte command: jr $ra (MIPS CPU)
   if (write(fd, buf, BYTES_TO_REPLACE) != BYTES_TO_REPLACE) printf("ERROR %d: %s!\n", errno, strerror(errno));

   // close memory device and shared library
   close(fd);
   dlclose(handle);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because process code in memory doesn't have write permission by default. To see the permissions of a process's memory, use `pmap`:

For example, shared libraries below have only `rx` permission at most:

```
sudo pmap 5869                                                                                                                    
5869:   vim supervisor_meeting-2017-05-22.txt
000055b391f62000   2604K r-x-- vim
000055b3923ed000     56K r---- vim
000055b3923fb000    100K rw--- vim
000055b392414000     60K rw---   [ anon ]
000055b393377000   2868K rw---   [ anon ]
00007fc59ef5a000     40K r-x-- libnss_files-2.24.so
00007fc59ef64000   2048K ----- libnss_files-2.24.so
00007fc59f164000      4K r---- libnss_files-2.24.so
00007fc59f165000      4K rw--- libnss_files-2.24.so
00007fc59f166000     24K rw---   [ anon ]

<..snip..>
```

I understand that you're trying to change this with mprotect - but you're also not checking the return value from the `mprotect()` call - this is probably failing for some reason.

Also, as an aside - `write()` is not guaranteed to write all bytes given to it, and is quite within it's design to return with no or a partial number of bytes written - I'd suggest you also change the code to reflect this.